# Can't figure out something in generics

Tags: scala

I'm very new to scala, and I came from Obj-C, so I'm not very familiar with generics. Here is what I'm doing:

```
class A[T <: Word](rules: Map[T, T]) {   
  def this(rulesStr: Map[String, String], i:Int) = {
    this(rulesStr map { case (k, v) => (new W(k), new W(v))})
  }
}
```

So, I'm trying to remake my map, from (string, string) to (W,W). W is class with underlying String, and extends Word. Here is its definition

```
class W(val underlying: String) extends Word
```

I'm getting error:

```
Error:(6, 19) type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[W,W]
 required: Map[T,T]
 this(rulesStr map { case (k, v) => (new W(k), new W(v))})
            ^
```

I can't figure out, what I'm doing wrong, because W inherited Word, and it is meeting requirements of T.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you need a `Map[T, T]` for any `T` the client chooses, which you can't do since you are constructing a `Map[W, W]`. For example if someone defined

```
case class OtherWord(s: String) extends Word
```

then they should be able to use `A` since `OtherWord` satisfies the constraints on `T`:

```
val a = A[OtherWord](...)
```

and in that case you would be passing a `Map[Word, Word]` where a `Map[OtherWord, OtherWord]` is required.

You could remove the type parameter:

```
class A(rules: Map[W, W]) {   
  def this(rulesStr: Map[String, String], i:Int) = {
    this(rulesStr map { case (k, v) => (new W(k), new W(v))})
  }
}
```

or require a `String => T` function be provided in the constructor

```
class A[T <: Word](rules: Map[T, T]) {   
  def this(rulesStr: Map[String, String], i:Int, f: String => T) = {
    this(rulesStr map { case (k, v) => (f(k), f(v))})
  }
}
```

Comment: Thing is, what I don't wanna user to choose `T`, if he uses alternative constructor. Actually, I don't need that type other than in that map. I just want to ensure, that key and value of map will be extending `Word`. Is it possible to do it some other way?

Comment: @AlfredZien - If the user can't choose `T` then you don't need generics at all - since you're using `W` then you know that the key/value types in the map extend `Word` since `W` does.

Comment: Got it. I just can write `class A(rules: Map[Word, Word])`, no need for generics. Thanks! Still getting confused with static types and multiple inheritance.